# Cloud-based IDE for Docker-based projects?

Tags: docker, ide, cloud, development-environment

I want to start converting some of my existing projects over to using Docker - mainly to improve the ease with which new developers can get started working and reduce environment-related bugs when deploying to production (I once had an issue where code worked perfectly in dev ***and*** staging only to find out that production had an out-dated version of MySQL)

The problem is that I like working with cloud-based IDEs. I currently use Cloud9, although I've started looking at CodeAnywhere and Codenvy recently to see if they'll fit my needs (so far: uncertain)

The problem I'm running into is that Docker doesn't seem to play nicely with many cloud-based IDEs.

- On Cloud9, your project (and associated repository) reside in a "workspace". One workspace is a Docker container running in non-privileged mode, so you cannot run Docker while within the workspace. This means any environment dependencies (Python, PHP, MySQL, etc) must be installed directly to the workspace OS
- CodeAnywhere similarly creates a "container" -- a Docker container where your code runs, and within which you cannot run Docker
- Codenvy seems a ***little*** closer to what I want, in that a "workspace" may consist of multiple "machines". This reminds me very much of a `docker-compose.yml` file. Your workspace may contain a database machine, a redis cache machine, and a PHP machine. However their hierarchy then places "projects" (and associated repositories) as a child of "workspaces" -- rather than the environment definition (and `docker-compose.yml` file) being a child of the project

The first two both support some notion of "SSH workspaces" -- instead of connecting to a container hosted by them, you can spin up a VM and connect to it directly. While this would allow me to run Docker, at a first glance it suffers one of two serious issues:

1. Every project resides in a single "workspace" - making it difficult from the IDE to keep work separate
2. Every project has their own "workspace", meaning every project has their own VM - leading to large monthly costs

Is there some other cloud-based IDE that will solve my issues, or is there some other way to use one of these three cloud-base IDEs that will work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question in a few different places and not just here. After several months there has been no complete answer, but I have gained a bit more information that I would like to pass along to anyone who stumbles upon the same issue.

### 1. Regarding Cloud9 and CodeAnywhere

When spinning up a new SSH workspace, you can specify not only the host, but also the root folder for the workspace. This means you can create multiple workspaces on a single VM and keep everything nice and separate.

There are a few caveats:

- In order to truly keep your workspaces separate, you must create a new user for each workspace. Otherwise someone in `workspaceA` can edit `../workspaceB/file`
- All workspaces will share the same disk space, so it's possible for someone working in one workspace to fill up the hard drive and cause issues for all other workspaces
- There's no easy way to spin up new workspaces. You have to log into the VM as an administrative user, create a new user, create a directory for the workspace, assign permissions, then set up a new SSH workspace. It may be possible to automate a large portion of this, though

### 2. Regarding CodeAnywhere specifically

CodeAnywhere promised full Docker support in Q4 of 2018. I've been waiting and haven't seen it yet. Keep your fingers crossed.

### 3. An alternate service

Now in 2018 there are ***over 50*** cloud-based IDEs. Everyone and their mother is making a "me too" business. So it stands to reason that at least one of them will work. While I haven't gone around trying them all, I did hear from someone that [OpenShift](https://openshift.io/) supports Docker.